# Call aspnet_regsql.exe from SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to call `aspnet_regsql.exe` from an SQL script?
thanks

Comment: aspnet_regsql can generate a sql script.  Check `-?` to see the command line options, or read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx):

```
xp_cmdshell 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe'
```

Answer (score 2):

`xp_cmdshell` alows you to call exe files form sql server

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\PrintToPDFConsole.exe'
```

Read more : [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx)