# Call .exe from SQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql, exe

Is there a way to run the following command line statement from an SQL script in a PostgreSQL database?

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M D:\postgresql\data\input.tif -F -t 100x100 public.demelevation > output.sql
```

I found something promising for Microsoft's SQL Server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278830/call-aspnet-regsql-exe-from-sql-script), but I couldn't find something similar for PostgreSQL.

Comment: There is a [`plsh` language handler](https://github.com/petere/plsh) for unix-based OS-es, however, I'm not sure if that could work on windows though. Anyway, there are several "untrusted" [language variants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html) (even for contrib modules), which can theoretically call a system command (e.g. `pltclu`, [`plperlu`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-trusted.html) and [`plpythonu`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html))

Comment: If the .exe is located on the same computer where `psql` is running you can use `\!` inside the SQL statement to run an external program.

Answer (score 1):

[you can use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) `COPY` for that. Think if it's a good idea to call programm from psql though. Also you will need superuser permissions for that.

Example:

```
t=# create table c (t text);
t=# copy (select 1) to program $$echo "whatever" -v >/tmp/12$$;
COPY 1
t=# copy c from program 'echo "whatever" -v';
COPY 1
t=# select * from c;
      t
-------------
 whatever -v
(1 row)

Time: 0.380 ms
t=# !\ cat /tmp/12
Invalid command \. Try \? for help.
t-# \! cat /tmp/12
whatever -v
```